# Regex to split SQL script but ignore splitting GO under commented script

Tags: sql, regex

I'm trying to parse a sort of big SQL script containing commands like create functions and store procedures. I want to split the file in strings whenever I find a `GO` statement (I want to execute it using ordinary ado.net instead of SMO).

The problem is that I haven't find a suitable regular expression for that so far. Using a simple `\bGO\b` ignoring case will split it. But will also split all go(s) inside a comment like

```
/*****************************\
sql statement 1
GO
sql statement 2
GO
\****************************/
```

My requirement is : Do not split the script if it is under comment even though the script contains GO statement. Suppose my entire script is as below :

```
sql statement 1
GO
/*****************************\
sql statement 2
GO
sql statement 3
GO
\****************************/
sql statement 4
```

Expected output should be like

```
First command :
sql statement 1

Second command :

/*****************************\
sql statement 2
GO
sql statement 3
GO
\****************************/
sql statement 4
```

Have any idea on this ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the comments and then split by `GO`:

```
/\/\**\\[^\\]*?\\\**\//    # match the comment

\/\**\\    # matches /*****\
[^\\]*?    # any text within the comments
\\\**\/    # matches \*****/
```

Remove above finds and split the result by `GO`.

Comment: I think he needs the `GO`s inside the comments to remain.

Comment: Thank you to mishik and Radu for your response. As Radu mentioned, i want to retain the commented script with uncommented script. For example if i have a script to create a stored procedure or trigger which can have some script commented in the middle of the script. While running this script to create a stored procedure or trigger, i should retain the commented script as well. I mean once the stored procedure or trigger is created in the database, I should be able to see the commented script inside the script of stored procedure/trigger. Thanks